# Intersection of array of set [Minizinc]

Tags: minizinc

I want create a constraint so that the intersection of the sets in the  table is not empty

```
array[1..4] of var set of int:tabofset;

constraint intersect(i in 1..4)(tabofset[i]) != {}
```

I have written it like that but there is no global **intersect** constraint, how to write this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

array_intersect(tabofset) != {}

but tabofset must have defined lb and ub to work. It cannot be of type int.